# C++ !! conversion to bool

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

In C++ there is a construction `!!` applicable to non bool values to convert it to bool. For instance:

```
int n = 12;

if ( !!n )
  std::<<cout << "n is true";
else
  std::<<cout << "n is false";
```

Is there any restrictions where it can be applied, or which types is applicable: POD, pointers, etc.?

Comment: Please use the  `{}` button in the editor to format code.

Comment: related? [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) ([search on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=safe+bool+idiom))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The restriction is that `operator!` must be defined for the type (and it must yield a type for which `operator!` is also defined)

Comment: So let's try to specify types: 1) POD (int, long, etc); 2) Pointers?; 3) Any custom classes which supports operator! ?

Comment: @Denis: the following type is POD, but doesn't work with `!!`: `struct a { int b; };`. The following type is POD, and does work: `bool`. So POD isn't a useful classification here.

Answer (score 5):

It works for any type that can be evaluated in a boolean context. So arithmetic types, pointer types (including pointer-to-(member)(function)), and anything with a conversion to one of those. Plus odds and ends like enum types, `std::nullptr_t`, and probably something else I've forgotten. 4/3 in C++11 defines what *contextually converted to bool* means, and that's what the built-in `operator!` does.

For all of these types, writing `if(!!n)` is redundant, you can write `if(n)` with the same meaning. `!!n` for such types means the same as `bool(n)` or `static_cast<bool>(n);`.

It also works for any type with an overloaded `operator!` that returns a type that can be converted to bool (or that returns a type with `operator!` overloaded to return `bool`).

If the leftmost `operator!` returns a type other than bool, then you might still be able to write `if(!!n)`, but `!!` doesn't act as a conversion to `bool`. It acts as a conversion to whatever type is returned.

Comment: I would actually call `!!` an anti-pattern.  If an object converts to `bool` or something equivalent (and very few should), then use it as a `bool` directly.  If it doesn't, it shouldn't support `!` either.  And most of time, it's far better to state explicitly what you are testing: `someInt == 0` (and not `!!someInt`), or `!someObj.isValid()`, rather than `!!someObj`, or even `someObj`.

Comment: I think the last paragraph is wrong.  If `!n` is something other than `bool` (because of a flagrant abuse of operator overloading), then `!!n` will call `!` on whatever type `!n` returns.  And for all non-user defined types, if `!` is legal, the results are `bool`.

Comment: @James: "If it doesn't, it shouldn't support ! either" - I think I agree, I'm just not sure enough to state it myself as a rule. I suspect that `!!` is most commonly used as a hangover from C89 (or older) code, where of course there is no boolean type, `!!n` is idiomatic for mapping an integer 0->0 and anything else ->1, and might used in fiddly constructs like `lookup_table[2*a + !!b];`.

Comment: @James: By "outer" `operator!` I mean the one on the left. What I had in mind in the last paragraph is that `A::operator!` returns `B`, and `B::operator!` returns `int`. This is sick and twisted, but the questioner is asking for "any restrictions" on `!!` used as a conversion to `bool`. This hypothetical stupid definition gives the result that `if(!!a)` compiles and does something that may or may not be meaningful, but `!!a` doesn't have type `bool`. You could convert `A` to `bool` with `!!!!a`, though!

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are good for your actual question.

However, just in case you were planning to use the code in your example to "simplify" your code (in that it makes the code shorter) I thought I would suggest that you don't do that.  Rather, simplify the meaning and check the integer for zero rather than a double negative on an integer.

```
if (n!=0) 
    { 
      //whatever
    }
```

Explicitly testing against zero has the benefit of being independent as to whether you remember the "zero is false" convention used in c++.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/329582/498253, and the comments below.

This is because for me,  `if(!!my_int)` is not very clear - its not obvious what is meant to happen, and to form a branch at this point looks like its going to cause problems.

**Previous snippet (so that the very useful comments make sense)**

```
bool my_bool = (n != 0) ? true : false; //whichever way you want it to work.
if (my_bool) 
  { 
    //whatever
  }
```

Comment: I prefer your style to keep code maximum obvious. However there are plenty of places where !! still used.

Comment: For integer types this is all ridiculous, just write `if(my_int)`. You can carry on adding noise as long as you like: `bool my_bool = !!((n!=0) ? true : false) ? true : !!false);`, but it is just noise. A C++ programmer must learn that in C++, integers can be used in a boolean context, and what that means, and then `if(my_int)` is perfectly readable, or `if(my_int != 0)` if you really dislike the int -> bool conversion. `!!` should be reserved for types that don't convert to `bool` but do have `operator!`, although some people use it to avoid typing `(bool)`, or in code migrated from C89.

Comment: @SteveJessop: well said.  I would delete my answer but I think you comment is useful - so its staying

Comment: @Tom the `(n != 0) ? true : false` is an anti-pattern.  What's wrong with just `n != 0`?

Comment: @SteveJessop Just writing `if (n)` is confusing as well, if `n` isn't boolean.  Say what you mean, and mean what you say: `if ( n != 0 )` (if `n` is an `int`).  Just because C++ supports an incredible number of implicit conversions doesn't mean you have to use them.

Comment: @James: I don't find it confusing, and I've been using C++ for maybe 20% as long as you have ;-) I somewhat dislike the int->bool conversion, and I would tend to write `if (n!=0)` myself, but I don't like to say that something is confusing unless I'm genuinely confused by it, or know someone who is. So I don't say that `if(n)` is confusing.

Comment: @SteveJessop, @James thanks for your helpful comments - I updated the answer in the light of them.  The following is related to whether if(n) is confusing (it depends whether you grew up to believe `0` is false, which  depends upon your language background): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329582/is-1-for-true-or-false/329944#329944

Comment: @SteveJessop I like the test to be explicit.  I still get confused by things like `if (p)` (where `p` is a pointer), and I usually have to think a minute or two for something like `if (strcmp(s1, s2))`  (which depends on the implicit conversion of `int` to `bool`).  The original proposal for `bool` in C++ deprecated all of the implicit conversions to `bool`; for various reasons, this deprecation was removed before the proposal was standardized, but I prefer to write code as if it were there.  (I'm a strong believer in strict type checking.)

Comment: @James: fair enough, and I agree that `if (strcmp(s1,s2))` takes a moment, just because in boolean context `strcmp` means "doesn't equal", which is slightly inconvenient IMO. I read `if(p)` as "if p points to anything", so that doesn't puzzle me -- less so than the integer, I think. But I suppose I must now say that I do know of someone who finds it an impediment, and one that isn't going to be fixed by familiarity with C++. If `if(strcmp(s1,s2))` costs 2 minutes of a highly qualified programmer's time, then it's way too expensive to use.

Answer (score 2):

The only restriction is that the object of the certain type should be convertible to bool or integer type.

For example, next type can not be converted :

```
struct A
{
  int a;
  float b;
};
```

but next can :

```
struct B
{
  int v;
  operator int()
  {
    return v;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`!!` is simply the `!` operator applied twice. It is applicable to all expressions where `!` can be used.

**Edit:**

Overloaded instances of operator `!` are assumed to be implemented as logical `not`.

Comment: You can, but defining an operator `!` that isn't the equivalence of logical `not` isn't good programming practice.

Comment: Well, I never said anything about good programming practice ;)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: have you heard of the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) and/or std iostreams? Also, Boost Proto and derived works (Expressive, Spirit) use operator! quite successfully returning stuff that isn't even convertible to bool